# malayalam font in android?

Tags: android

i want to develop an application which contain malyalam text for  that i want to add malayalam font.. is this compatible on all android devices.can any one please help me to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://narayam.in/mobile/android/fonts/
Here are some list of Malayalam fonts for Android (all in APK file format)

Comment: http://javatechig.com/2013/03/19/using-external-fonts-in-android-view/

Comment: Did you got any solution for this? Stuck with same problem...:(

Comment: Malayalam is not compatible with all device. Malayalam is supported from 4.0 onwards. Though we can use malayalam in later version its shows some special characters. Even the malayalam is showing nicely in 4.0 onwards I cant find the name anywhere in Locale languages. It have Bengali,Marathi,Tamil and Hindi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add ur font file in assets folder of your project, then with the help of `setTypeface()` function set the font for textview. I have't try'd it bt i think u will surely find it helpful.

```
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAsset(),"malyalam.fnt");
```

and then add it to your textview like below

```
textView.setTypeFace(typeFace);
```

hope this will work for u, keeping my fingers crossed :)

Answer (score 6):

Malayalam Font has rendering problem in android 2.2 to 4.0 .So what we need to do is we need to convert the malayalam unicode to Corresponding Ascii of the selcted malaylam font and After the Ascii convertion Just User the type face.

Example

> The Font I am using Here is Kartikafont

```
tx_mal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "karthika.TTF");

String malword = "ഒന്നര ദശാബ്ദം മുമ്പ് സിറ്റിയിലൂടെ പ്രീമിയം ബ്രാന്‍ഡായി ഇന്ത്യക്കാരുടെ മനസില്‍ കയറിക്കൂടിയ ഹോണ്ടയുടെ നില പരുങ്ങലിലായിട്ട് കുറച്ചുകാലമായി. അഞ്ചു $k$k വര്‍ഷമായി ജപ്പാന്‍ കമ്പനിയുടെ ബാലന്‍സ് ഷീറ്റില്‍ അവശേഷിച്ചത് നഷ്ടത്തിന്റെ കണക്കുകള്‍ മാത്രം. ഡീസല്‍ മോഡലിന്റെ അഭാവമായിരുന്നു എല്ലാത്തിനും കാരണം. ഒടുവില്‍ ഡീസലിനു പിന്നാലെ പോകാന്‍ ഹോണ്ടയും തീരുമാനിച്ചു. ആ വഴിയ്ക്കുള്ള ആദ്യ ശ്രമമാണ് അമെയ്സ് എന്ന കോംപാക്ട് സെഡാന്‍ . എന്തായാലും ഹോണ്ടയുടെ പുതിയ നീക്കം പിഴച്ചില്ല";
         String malword =malword .replaceAll("അ", "A")

            .replaceAll("ആ", "B").replaceAll("ഇ", "C")
            .replaceAll("ഈ", "Cu").replaceAll("ഉ", "D")
            .replaceAll("ഊ", "Du").replaceAll("ഋ", "E")
            .replaceAll("എ", "F").replaceAll("ഏ", "G")
            .replaceAll("ജ്യോ", "Ptym").replaceAll("ഞ്ഞൊ", "sªm")
            .replaceAll("ഭോ", "t`m").replaceAll("ഐ", "sF")
            .replaceAll("ഒ", "H").replaceAll("ഹോ", "tlm")
            .replaceAll("പ്രൊ", "{s]m").replaceAll("ത്തോ", "t¯m")
            .replaceAll("ഓ", "Hm").replaceAll("ഔ", "Hu")
            .replaceAll("ഡ്രോ", "{tUm").replaceAll("പ്രൌ", "{s]u")
            .replaceAll("ഞൊ", "sRm").replaceAll("ഷ്യോ", "jtym")
            .replaceAll("റ്റൊ", "säm").replaceAll("യൊ", "sbm")
            .replaceAll("ക്തേ", "tà").replaceAll("ക്തെ", "sà")
            .replaceAll("മൌ", "sau").replaceAll("ഗ്രൌ", "{sKu")
            .replaceAll("വ്യോ", "htym").replace("ല്ലോ", "tÃm")
            .replaceAll("ദോ", "tZm").replaceAll("ബ്ലോ", "t»m")
            .replaceAll("മ്യേ", "aty").replaceAll("ഗൌ", "sKu")
            .replace("ഗ്രേ", "{tK").replaceAll("ന്നൊ", "s¶m")
            .replaceAll("ന്നോ", "t¶m").replaceAll("ഗ്ലോ", "t¥m")
            .replaceAll("ണ്ടോ", "tîm").replaceAll("ദ്യോ", "Ztym")
            .replaceAll("ഫ്രെ", "{s^").replaceAll("ക്ത്യ", "ày")
            .replaceAll("ക്തൈ", "ssà").replaceAll("ക്ത", "à")
            .replaceAll("ക്ഷ്യ", "£y").replaceAll("ക്ഷെ", "s£")
            .replaceAll("ക്ഷേ", "t£").replaceAll("ക്ഷൈ", "ss£")
            .replaceAll("ക്ഷ", "£").replaceAll("ക്ടെ", "sÎ")
            .replaceAll("ക്ടേ", "tÎ").replaceAll("ക്ട", "Î")
            .replaceAll("ങ്കെ", "s¦").replaceAll("ങ്കേ", "t¦")
            .replaceAll("ങ്കൈ", "ss¦").replaceAll("ന്മോ", "t·m")
            .replaceAll("ങ്ക", "¦").replaceAll("ക്ലെ", "s¢")
            .replaceAll("ക്ലേ", "t¢").replaceAll("ക്ലൈ", "ss¢")
            .replaceAll("ക്ല", "¢").replaceAll("ക്കേ", "t¡")
            .replaceAll("ക്കോ", "t¡m").replaceAll("ക്കെ", "s¡")
            .replaceAll("കൊ", "sIm").replaceAll("സൌ", "sku")
            .replaceAll("കെ", "sI").replaceAll("കോ", "tIm")
            .replaceAll("കേ", "tI").replaceAll("പ്പോ", "t¸m")
            .replaceAll("ളോ", "tfm").replaceAll("പ്രോ", "{t]m")
            .replaceAll("ല്ലേ", "tÃ").replaceAll("മ്പോ", "t¼m")
            .replaceAll("ക്വ", "Iz").replaceAll("ക്രൈ", "ss{I")
            .replaceAll("ക്രോ", "t{Im").replaceAll("ക്രേ", "t{I")
            .replaceAll("ക്രൊ", "s{Im").replaceAll("ക്രെ", "s{I")
            .replaceAll("ക്ര", "{I").replaceAll("ക്യ", "Iy")
            .replaceAll("ക്കൈ", "ss¡").replaceAll("ക്ക", "¡")
            .replaceAll("കൈ", "ssI").replaceAll("ക", "I")
            .replaceAll("ഖേ", "tJ").replaceAll("ഖൈ", "ssJ")
            .replaceAll("ഖെ", "sJ").replaceAll("ഖ്വ", "Jz")
            .replaceAll("ഖ്യ", "Jy").replaceAll("ഖ", "J")
            .replaceAll("ഗ്ലെ", "s¥").replaceAll("ഗ്ലേ", "t¥")
            .replaceAll("ഗ്ലൈ", "ss¥").replaceAll("ഗ്ല", "¥")
            .replaceAll("ഗ്ഗേ", "t¤").replaceAll("ഗ്ഗൈ", "ss¤")
            .replaceAll("ഗ്ഗെ", "s¤").replaceAll("ഗൈ", "ssK")
            .replaceAll("ഗൊ", "sKm").replaceAll("ഗെ", "sK")
            .replaceAll("ഗ്വ", "Kz").replaceAll("ഗ്യ", "Ky")
            .replaceAll("ഗൃ", "Kr").replaceAll("ഗ്രൈ", "ss{K")
            .replaceAll("ഗ്ര", "{K").replaceAll("ഗ്ഗ", "¤")
            .replaceAll("ഗോ", "tKm").replaceAll("ഗേ", "tK")
            .replaceAll("റോ", "tdm").replaceAll("ഗ", "K")
            .replaceAll("ഘൈ", "ssL").replaceAll("ഘൊ", "sLm")
            .replaceAll("ഘെ", "sL").replaceAll("ഘോ", "tLm")
            .replaceAll("ഘേ", "tL").replaceAll("ഘ", "L")
            .replaceAll("ങ്ങൈ", "ss§").replaceAll("ങ്ങെ", "s§")
            .replaceAll("ങ്ങേ", "t§").replaceAll("ങ്ങ്യ", "§y")
            .replaceAll("ങ്ങ", "§").replaceAll("ങേ", "tM")
            .replaceAll("ങൈ", "ssM").replaceAll("ങെ", "sM")
            .replaceAll("ങ", "M").replaceAll("ഞ്ചൈ", "ss©")
            .replaceAll("ഞ്ചെ", "s©").replaceAll("ഞ്ചേ", "t©")
            .replaceAll("ഞ്ച്യ", "©y").replaceAll("ഞ്ച", "©")
            .replaceAll("ച്ചേ", "t¨").replaceAll("ച്ചൈ", "ss¨")
            .replaceAll("ച്ചെ", "s¨").replaceAll("ചോ", "tNm")
            .replaceAll("ചേ", "tN").replaceAll("ചൈ", "ssN")
            .replaceAll("ചൊ", "sNm").replaceAll("ചെ", "sN")
            .replaceAll("ച്ര", "{N").replaceAll("ച്യ", "Ny")
            .replaceAll("ച്ച", "¨").replaceAll("ച", "N")
            .replaceAll("ഛൈ", "ssO").replaceAll("ഛെ", "sO")
            .replaceAll("ഛേ", "tO").replaceAll("ഛ", "O")
            .replaceAll("ജ്ഞൈ", "ssÚ").replaceAll("ജ്ഞെ", "sÚ")
            .replaceAll("ജ്ഞേ", "tÚ").replaceAll("ജ്ഞ", "Ú")
            .replaceAll("ജ്ജേ", "tÖ").replaceAll("ജ്ജൈ", "ssÖ")
            .replaceAll("ജ്ജെ", "sÖ").replaceAll("ജ്ജ", "Ö")
            .replaceAll("ജൈ", "ssP").replaceAll("ജൊ", "sPm")
            .replaceAll("ജെ", "sP").replaceAll("ജ്വ", "Pz")
            .replaceAll("ജ്യ", "Py").replaceAll("ജ്ര", "{P")
            .replaceAll("ജോ", "tPm").replaceAll("ജേ", "tP")
            .replaceAll("ജ", "P").replaceAll("ഝൈ", "ssQ")
            .replaceAll("ഝെ", "sQ").replaceAll("ഝേ", "tQ")
            .replaceAll("ത്സ്യ", "Qy").replaceAll("ഝ", "Q")
            .replaceAll("ഞ്ഞൈ", "ssª").replaceAll("ഞ്ഞെ", "sª")
            .replaceAll("ഞ്ഞേ", "tª").replaceAll("ഞ്ഞ", "ª")
            .replaceAll("ഞൈ", "ssR").replaceAll("ഞെ", "sR")
            .replaceAll("ഞേ", "tR").replaceAll("ഞ", "R")
            .replaceAll("ന്റെ", "sâ").replaceAll("ന്റേ", "tâ")
            .replaceAll("ന്റ", "â").replaceAll("ണ്ടൈ", "ssî")
            .replaceAll("ണ്ടെ", "sî").replaceAll("ണ്ടേ", "tî")
            .replaceAll("ണ്ട്യ", "îy").replaceAll("ണ്ട", "î")
            .replaceAll("ട്ട്യ", "«y").replaceAll("ട്ടൈ", "ss«")
            .replaceAll("ട്ടെ", "s«").replaceAll("ട്രൈ", "ss{S")
            .replaceAll("ട്രോ", "t{Sm").replaceAll("ട്രേ", "t{S")
            .replaceAll("ട്രെ", "s{S").replaceAll("ടൈ", "ssS")
            .replaceAll("ടൊ", "sSm").replaceAll("ടെ", "sS")
            .replaceAll("ട്ര", "{S").replaceAll("ട്വ", "Sz")
            .replaceAll("ട്യ", "Sy").replaceAll("ട്ടോ", "t«m")
            .replaceAll("ട്ടേ", "t«").replaceAll("ണോ", "tWm")
            .replaceAll("ഷോ", "tjm").replaceAll("ട്ട", "«")
            .replaceAll("ടോ", "tSm").replaceAll("ടേ", "tS")
            .replaceAll("ട", "S").replaceAll("ഠൈ", "ssT")
            .replaceAll("ഠെ", "sT").replaceAll("ഠേ", "tT")
            .replaceAll("ഠ്യ", "Ty").replaceAll("ഠ", "T")
            .replaceAll("ഡ്രൈ", "ss{U").replaceAll("ഡ്രേ", "t{U")
            .replaceAll("ഡ്രെ", "s{U").replaceAll("ഡൈ", "ssU")
            .replaceAll("ഡെ", "sU").replaceAll("ഡ്ര", "{U")
            .replaceAll("ഡേ", "tU").replaceAll("ഡോ", "tUm")
            .replaceAll("ഡ", "U").replaceAll("ഢൈ", "ssV")
            .replaceAll("ഢെ", "sV").replaceAll("ഢേ", "tV")
            .replaceAll("ഢ", "V").replaceAll("ണ്മൈ", "ss×")
            .replaceAll("ണ്മെ", "s×").replaceAll("ണ്മേ", "t×")
            .replaceAll("ണ്മ", "×").replaceAll("ണ്ണൈ", "ss®")
            .replaceAll("ണ്ണെ", "s®").replaceAll("ണൈ", "ssW")
            .replaceAll("ണെ", "sW").replaceAll("ണ്‍", "¬")
            .replaceAll("ണ്ണേ", "t®").replaceAll("ണ്ണ", "®")
            .replaceAll("ണേ", "tW").replaceAll("ണ", "W")
            .replaceAll("ത്ഥൈ", "ss°").replaceAll("ത്ഥെ", "s°")
            .replaceAll("ത്ഥേ", "t°").replaceAll("ത്ഥ്യ", "°y")
            .replaceAll("ത്ഥ", "°").replaceAll("ത്മൈ", "ssß")
            .replaceAll("ത്മെ", "sß").replaceAll("ത്മേ", "tß")
            .replaceAll("ത്മ", "ß").replaceAll("ത്തൈ", "ss¯")
            .replaceAll("ത്തെ", "s¯").replaceAll("ന്തൈ", "ss´")
            .replaceAll("ന്തെ", "s´").replaceAll("തൈ", "ssX")
            .replaceAll("തൊ", "sXm").replaceAll("തെ", "sX")
            .replaceAll("ത്വ", "Xz").replaceAll("ന്ത്ര", "{´")
            .replaceAll("ന്ത്യ", "´y").replaceAll("ന്തേ", "t´")
            .replaceAll("ന്തോ", "t´m").replaceAll("ന്ത", "´")
            .replaceAll("ത്യേ", "tXy").replaceAll("ത്യ", "Xy")
            .replaceAll("തൃ", "Xr").replaceAll("ത്രൈ", "ss{X")
            .replaceAll("ത്രോ", "t{Xm").replaceAll("ത്രൊ", "t{Xm")
            .replaceAll("ത്രേ", "t{X").replaceAll("ത്രെ", "s{X")
            .replaceAll("ത്ര", "{X").replaceAll("ത്തേ", "t¯")
            .replaceAll("ത്ത", "¯").replaceAll("തോ", "tXm")
            .replaceAll("തേ", "tX").replaceAll("ത", "X")
            .replaceAll("ഥൈ", "ssY").replaceAll("ഥെ", "sY")
            .replaceAll("ഥേ", "tY").replaceAll("ഥ", "Y")
            .replaceAll("ദ്ധേ", "t²").replaceAll("ദ്ധൈ", "ss²")
            .replaceAll("ദ്ധെ", "s²").replaceAll("ദ്ധ", "²")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ദൈ", "ssÐ").replaceAll("ബ്ദെ", "sÐ")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ദേ", "tÐ").replaceAll("ബ്ദ", "Ð")
            .replaceAll("ന്ദൈ", "ssµ").replaceAll("ന്ദെ", "sµ")
            .replaceAll("ന്ദേ", "tµ").replaceAll("ന്ദ്രേ", "t{µ")
            .replaceAll("ന്ദ്രൈ", "ss{µ").replaceAll("ന്ദ്രെ", "s{µ")
            .replaceAll("ന്ദ്ര", "{µ").replaceAll("ന്ദ", "µ")
            .replaceAll("ദ്ദൈ", "ss±").replaceAll("ദ്ദെ", "s±")
            .replaceAll("ദ്ദേ", "t±").replaceAll("ദ്ദ", "±")
            .replaceAll("ദൈ", "ssZ").replaceAll("ദെ", "sZ")
            .replaceAll("ദ്വൈ", "ssZz").replaceAll("ദ്വേ", "tZz")
            .replaceAll("ദ്വ", "Zz").replaceAll("ദ്യെ", "sZy")

            .replaceAll("ന്റെ", "sâ").replaceAll("ന്റേ", "tâ")
            .replaceAll("ന്&zwj;റ", "â").replaceAll("ന്റ", "â")
            .replaceAll("ന്&zwj;", "³").replaceAll("ന്‍", "³")
            .replaceAll("ന്നൈ", "ss¶").replaceAll("ന്നെ", "s¶")
            .replaceAll("ന്നേ", "t¶").replaceAll("ന്ന", "¶")
            .replaceAll("ന്മൈ", "ss∙").replaceAll("ന്മെ", "s∙")
            .replaceAll("ന്മേ", "t∙").replaceAll("ന്മ", "∙")
            .replace("നൈ", "ss\\").replace("നൊ", "s\\m")
            .replace("നെ", "s\\").replace("ന്വേ", "t\\z")
            .replace("ന്വെ", "s\\z").replace("ന്വ", "\\z")
            .replace("ന്യ", "\\y").replace("നോ", "t\\m")
            .replace("നേ", "t\\").replace("ന", "\\")
            .replaceAll("മ്പൈ", "ss¼").replaceAll("മ്പെ", "s¼")
            .replaceAll("മ്പ്യ", "¼y").replaceAll("മ്പേ", "t¼")
            .replaceAll("മ്പ", "¼").replaceAll("ല്പെ", "så")
            .replaceAll("ല്പേ", "tå").replaceAll("ല്പ", "å")
            .replaceAll("പ്ലേ", "ts¹").replaceAll("പ്ലൈ", "ss¹")
            .replaceAll("പ്ലെ", "s¹").replaceAll("പ്ല", "¹")
            .replaceAll("പ്പേ", "t¸").replaceAll("പ്പൈ", "ss¸")
            .replaceAll("പ്പെ", "s¸").replaceAll("പൈ", "ss]")
            .replaceAll("പൊ", "s]m").replaceAll("പെ", "s]")
            .replaceAll("പ്യ", "]y").replaceAll("പ്രേ", "t{]")
            .replaceAll("പ്രൈ", "ss{]").replaceAll("പ്രെ", "s{]")
            .replaceAll("പ്ര", "{]").replaceAll("പ്പേ", "t¸")
            .replaceAll("പ്പ", "¸").replaceAll("പോ", "t]m")
            .replaceAll("പേ", "t]").replaceAll("പ", "]")
            .replaceAll("ഫ്ലൈ", "^vssf").replaceAll("ഫ്ലെ", "^vsf")
            .replaceAll("ഫ്ലേ", "^vtf").replaceAll("ഫ്ല", "^vf")
            .replaceAll("ഫൈ", "ss^").replaceAll("ഫൊ", "s^m")
            .replaceAll("ഫെ", "s^").replaceAll("ഫോ", "t^m")
            .replaceAll("ഫേ", "t^").replaceAll("ഫ്ര", "{^")
            .replaceAll("ഫ", "^").replaceAll("ബ്ലൈ", "ss»")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ലെ", "s»").replaceAll("ബ്ലേ", "t»")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ല", "»").replaceAll("ബ്ബൈ", "ssº")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ബെ", "sº").replaceAll("ബൈ", "ss_")
            .replaceAll("ബൊ", "s_m").replaceAll("ബെ", "s_")
            .replaceAll("ബ്രേ", "t{_").replaceAll("ബ്രൈ", "ss{_")
            .replaceAll("ബ്രെ", "s{_").replaceAll("ബ്ര", "{_")
            .replaceAll("ബ്ബേ", "tº").replaceAll("ബ്ബ", "º")
            .replaceAll("ബോ", "t_m").replaceAll("ബേ", "t_")
            .replaceAll("ബ", "_").replaceAll("ഭൈ", "ss`")
            .replaceAll("ഭെ", "s`").replaceAll("ഭ്വ", "`z")
            .replaceAll("ഭ്ര", "{`").replaceAll("ഭ്യ", "`y")
            .replaceAll("ഭൃ", "`r").replaceAll("ഭേ", "t`")
            .replaceAll("ഭ", "`").replaceAll("മ്മൈ", "ss½")
            .replaceAll("മ്മെ", "s½").replaceAll("മൈ", "ssa")
            .replaceAll("മൊ", "sam").replaceAll("മെ", "sa")
            .replaceAll("മ്യ", "ay").replaceAll("മൃ", "ar")
            .replaceAll("മ്മേ", "t½").replaceAll("മ്മ", "½")
            .replaceAll("മോ", "tam").replaceAll("മേ", "ta")
            .replaceAll("മ", "a").replaceAll("ല്യ", "ey")
            .replaceAll("ര്യ", "cy").replaceAll("ഷ്യ", "jy")
            .replaceAll("ഹ്യ", "ly").replaceAll("സ്യേ", "tky")
            .replaceAll("സ്യ", "ky").replaceAll("ശ്യ", "iy")
            .replaceAll("വ്യ", "hy").replaceAll("യ്യൈ", "ss¿")
            .replaceAll("യ്യെ", "s¿").replaceAll("യോ", "tbm")
            .replaceAll("യൈ", "ssb").replaceAll("യെ", "sb")
            .replaceAll("യ്യേ", "t¿").replaceAll("യ്യ", "¿")
            .replaceAll("യേ", "tb").replaceAll("യ", "b")
            .replaceAll("ഹ്ര", "{l").replaceAll("സ്രേ", "t{k")
            .replaceAll("സ്ര", "{k").replaceAll("വ്ര", "{h")
            .replaceAll("ശ്രേ", "t{i").replaceAll("ശ്ര", "{i")
            .replaceAll("രൈ", "ssc").replaceAll("രൊ", "scm")
            .replaceAll("രെ", "sc").replaceAll("ര്വ", "cz")
            .replaceAll("ര്&zwj;", "À").replaceAll("ര്‍", "À")
            .replaceAll("ര്യ", "cy").replaceAll("രോ", "tcm")
            .replaceAll("രേ", "tc").replaceAll("ര", "c")
            .replaceAll("റ്റൈ", "ssä").replaceAll("റ്റെ", "sä")
            .replaceAll("റ്റേ", "tä").replaceAll("റ്റോ", "täm")
            .replaceAll("റ്റ", "ä").replaceAll("റൈ", "ssd")
            .replaceAll("റെ", "sd").replaceAll("റേ", "td")
            .replaceAll("റ", "d").replaceAll("ഹ്ലെ", "sË")
            .replaceAll("ഹ്ലേ", "tË").replaceAll("ഹ്ല", "Ë")
            .replaceAll("ശ്ലെ", "sÇ").replaceAll("ശ്ലേ", "tÇ")
            .replaceAll("ശ്ല", "Ç").replaceAll("ല്ലൈ", "ssÃ")
            .replaceAll("ല്ലൊ", "sÃm").replaceAll("ല്ലെ", "sÃ")
            .replaceAll("ലൈ", "sse").replaceAll("ലൊ", "sem")
            .replaceAll("ലെ", "se").replaceAll("ല്ല്വ", "Ãz")
            .replaceAll("ല്ല", "Ã").replaceAll("ല്&zwj;", "Â")
            .replaceAll("ല്‍", "Â").replaceAll("ല്ല്യ", "Ãy")
            .replaceAll("ല്ലോ", "tÃm").replaceAll("ല്ലേ", "tÃ")
            .replaceAll("ല്ല", "Ã").replaceAll("ലോ", "tem")
            .replaceAll("ലേ", "te").replaceAll("ല", "e")
            .replaceAll("ള്ള", "Å").replaceAll("ള്&zwj;", "Ä")
            .replaceAll("ള്‍", "Ä").replaceAll("ള്ളൈ", "ssÅ")
            .replaceAll("ള്ളെ", "sÅ").replaceAll("ളൈ", "ssf")
            .replaceAll("ളെ", "sf").replaceAll("ള്ള", "Å")
            .replaceAll("ള്ളേ", "tÅ").replaceAll("ളേ", "tf")
            .replaceAll("ള", "f").replaceAll("ഴൈ", "ssg")
            .replaceAll("ഴെ", "sg").replaceAll("ഴേ", "tg")
            .replaceAll("ഴ", "g").replaceAll("ഷ്വൈ", "ssjz")
            .replaceAll("ഷ്വെ", "sjz").replaceAll("ഷ്വ", "jz")
            .replaceAll("ഹ്വ", "lz").replaceAll("സ്വേ", "tkz")
            .replaceAll("സ്വൈ", "sskz").replaceAll("സ്വെ", "skz")
            .replaceAll("സ്വ", "kz").replaceAll("വ്വൈ", "ssÆ")
            .replaceAll("വ്വെ", "sÆ").replaceAll("വൈ", "ssh")
            .replaceAll("വെ", "sh").replaceAll("ശ്വേ", "tiz")
            .replaceAll("ശ്വ", "iz").replaceAll("വ്വേ", "tÆ")
            .replaceAll("വ്വ", "Æ").replaceAll("വേ", "th")
            .replaceAll("വോ", "thm").replaceAll("വ", "h")
            .replaceAll("ശ്ശൈ", "ssÈ").replaceAll("ശ്ശെ", "sÈ")
            .replaceAll("ശൈ", "ssi").replaceAll("ശൊ", "sim")
            .replaceAll("ശെ", "si").replaceAll("ശ്രേ", "t{i")
            .replaceAll("ശ്ര", "{i").replaceAll("ശ്ശേ", "tÈ")
            .replaceAll("ശ്ശ", "È").replaceAll("ശോ", "tim")
            .replaceAll("ശേ", "ti").replaceAll("ശ", "i")
            .replaceAll("ഷൈ", "ssj").replaceAll("ഷെ", "sj")
            .replaceAll("ഷേ", "tj").replaceAll("ഷ", "j")
            .replaceAll("സ്സൈ", "ssÊ").replaceAll("സ്സെ", "sÊ")
            .replaceAll("സൈ", "ssk").replaceAll("സെ", "sk")
            .replaceAll("സ്സ", "Ê").replaceAll("സ്സേ", "tÊ")
            .replaceAll("സേ", "tk").replaceAll("സോ", "tkm")
            .replaceAll("സ", "k").replaceAll("ഹൈ", "ssl")
            .replaceAll("ഹെ", "sl").replaceAll("ഹേ", "tl")
            .replaceAll("ഹ", "l").replaceAll("ാ", "m").replaceAll("ി", "n")
            .replaceAll("ീ", "o").replaceAll("ു", "p").replaceAll("ൂ", "q")
            .replaceAll("ഃ", "x").replaceAll("്", "v").replaceAll("ം", "w")
            .replaceAll("ൗ", "u").replaceAll("ൃ", "r").replaceAll("-", "þ");
 tx_mal .setTypeface(tf);
    tx_mal .setText(malword );
```

This Will Solve the malayalam Rendering(PLEASE USE KARTIKA FONT )

Comment: Malayalam font has rendering problem not only in android 2.2 to 4.0, it's also there in 4.4.2. I have a doubt. In my app there are certain malayalam names which are obtained from the webserver and stored it in an arraylist. Sometimes the arraylist may be very large due to data. Now I need to display it in my app. So what should I do in this case to display it in proper malayalam in my app?? Please I'm waiting for your reply eagerly...

Comment: @TeeJay  is the data comming from server is like unicode or ascii format

Comment: Is the data coming from server is like Unicode or ASCII format? If Unicode, use the above solution . in above solution i had converted max Unicode to ASCII of kartikafont. But still some Unicode is missed but you can find correspnding unicode and ascii formate from web as ur needs and replace those data.

Comment: The data in the mysql database is in the form UTF-8 format. I have tested using an html page by sending request to the server, and then displaying it correctly in malayalam in the browser itself. It's in UTF-8 format as I had used the <meta charset="utf-8"> code in the html to convert to utf-8 format and now it displays correctly as malayalam. Now I only need to send that data to the android. Then the receiving data would be also in UTF-8 format in android.

Comment: so what is the real issue is it about handling the data or showing the malayalam font?

Comment: Some of the characters such as ണ്ട് are displaying as weird characters. How can correct it? Can you please help me..I have a doubt. you have used replaceAll("ണ്ട", "î") in your code. How did you choose that?? Can you please explain the logic behind it..

Comment: Also some characters are displaying as square boxes in some phones such as galaxy ace having custom rom 4.4.2 cyanogenmode. Whereas it is displaying correctly in some others such as xperia m. How can this problem be cleared??

Comment: Also the word മാധ്യമം is shown as മാധ് യമം (actually there is no space between ധ് and യ. but to show here correctly I have used space in between them.). How do I correct these type of mistakes?? Is it due to the font which I have used (karthika font)?

Comment: Its not about logic what i did is that i convert the malayalam words to asciiiof the the kartika font

Comment: The site i used to convert unicode malayam font to ascii is not avilable now.

Comment: Then is there any other way to convert malayalam font to ascii now??

Comment: It was a site smc.org which is not avililable . I try but did not get a new one.sorry

Answer (score 2):

Use [adobe flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html). It will work on all android phones having Adobe AIR support. Development is very simple. If you are using flex to build android application, which will support all unicode languages including Malayalam.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change your localization preferences in Settings? That might help you see if malayalam is even available on Android. If you do have malayalam in the list of localizations, then select it. If the text on the menus shows up as "boxes", then Malayalam is not supported as of now. To do this in code, you can try the following:

```
Locale[] lArray = this.getAvailableLocales();  
for(int i = 0; i < lArray.size(); i++) {
   log.v(this.toString(), "Locale = " + getDisplayLanguage(lArray[i]));
}
```

The above code is by no means perfect as I have not tested it. But something on these lines should suffice.

HTH,
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
Typeface typeFace =Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
textView.setText("നിങ്ങൾക്കിവിടെ മലയാളവും ഇംഗ്ലീഷും (english) print  ചെയ്യാം");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TextView tv;
tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface Malayalam = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");
       tv.setTypeface(Malayalam);
tv.setText("ജീവിതത്തിന്‍റെ സൗഭാഗ്യമാണ്");
```