# How to convert ISO-8859-5 encoded json array to utf-8 or malayalam

Tags: android, utf-8

I am try to develop a android application to display malayalam news. I have database that contains `ISO-8859-5` charter entity.

**Example:**

`'&#231;&#193;x&#222; &#230;&#216;aV &#230;&#230;&#181;&#206;&#222;x&#162;'`

I want to display it in malayalam fonts. What should i do?

Comment: I believe you need to re-encode your db data.

Comment: Are you the creator of db? then it's easy to do according to language that you write to db with

Comment: The db used for a php website. The website is in malayalam langauage. In DB have ISO-8859-5 chareterset entity.I want to display it in android application without modifing db.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,you should download malayam ttf file and store it in asset folder and use that in your code refer following code`TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview03);
>   Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Molot.otf");
>   text.setTypeface(tf);`

Comment: I try this except. I have AnjaliOldLipi.ttf. But didnt get anything.

Comment: what did u get exactly during this execution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190833/how-to-set-textview-in-malayalam-fontan-indian-local-language-in-android-2-2      check this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930896/malayalam-font-in-android  check this link also

Comment: Guys, I can view malayalam when using typeface.But my db values are in HTML code,  Ex:'&#231;&#193;x&#222; &#230;&#216;aV &#230;&#230;&#181;&#206;&#222;x&#162;' It cannot display in malayalam while using typeface.